# GLSL texture(...) function fails

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a GL 3.3 context setup and am using GLSL shaders (vertex and fragment only) with the directive:

```
#version 330 core
```

I have also setup a uniform sampler2DShadow object in the fragment shader like so:

```
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap
```

but when using the following function to evaluate the map, GLSL stop's working. The strange thing is that there is no compilation or linking errors - it just stops working (i.e no object's being drawn). As soon as I comment the following line:

```
aVariable = texture(shadowMap, vec3(ShadowCoord.xy, ShadowCoord.z/ShadowCoord.w));
```

all starts working. Is there any reason why this would happen or could it be a bug in the GL driver?

Comment: Hmm, the line you pasted so far looks like a statement with no effect. Maybe you confuse some buggy compiler. But hard to tell.

Comment: Do you have the uniform set properly so that it references a 2D texture with `GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE` set to enable comparison?

Comment: @RetoKoradi I do have this set.

Comment: And it's a depth texture? I would also try a `glValidateProgram()` call when you're ready for the draw call, and see if it points out any problems.

Comment: Thanks @RetoKoradi, I tried validating after my draw call and I am now getting the error `Validation failed! - Different sampler types for same sample texture unit in fragment shader` - I have ensured that the same texture unit is not used for another texture.

Comment: That error sounds like its complaining about you having multiple samplers of different types (2d, 2dshadow, 2darray, cube, 3d, etc) referencing the same texture unit. Basically you are saying you want to read the same texture as different types of data.
http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/159510

Comment: Exactly. Do you use other samplers in your shader? Check all the `glUniform1i()` calls where you set the texture unit for each sampler, and make sure that they all set different values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RetoKoradi for getting me on the right track with his debugging methods. In the end, this issue came down to the same texture unit being assigned to different sampler types (thanks @CynicismRising). I ensured this was the problem by disabling any other texture units I had allocated and the shadow functions began to work. For some reason there was a bug in the `glUniform1f(...)` that meant the texture unit was not being set correctly.